# Passed data from JSP to Servlet returning null in Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="newtable">
                <!-- <caption id="tablehead">Rooms are available!</caption> -->

              <!--       <tr class="hover"> -->
                    <tr>
                        <th>Room No</th>
                        <th>AC</th>
                        <th>Deluxe</th>
                        <th>Tariff</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach var="room" items="${myrooms}">
                        <tr bgcolor="#4B476F" onMouseOver="this.bgColor='gold';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#4B476F';">

                            <td class="nr">1</td>
                            <td name="ac"><c:out value="${room.ac}" /></td>
                            <td name="deluxe"><c:out value="${room.deluxe}" /></td>
                            <td>&#8377;<c:out value="${room.price}" /></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="mybutton" onclick="location.href='passtopayment'">Pay</button> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
```

I want to get the td value for AC and Deluxe column on click of the corresponding row. However, when the execute the following servlet code I get, null null is printed. Please help!

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String ac = request.getParameter("ac");
    String deluxe = request.getParameter("deluxe");

    out.println(ac);
    out.println(deluxe);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Where is `form` tag to submit to server side?

Comment: How are you submitting your request parameters to the Servlet ?

Comment: I am not sure about how your logic (name for td) will work. Also you are iterating list `myrooms`. So there may be **n** number of rows. So you can't receive those values using `request.getParameter` and put it in `String` datatype.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `location.href='passtopayment'` that is not the correct way to submit a form.

It's just a like a separate request to the Servlet nothing will be send to the Servlet.

You should use `form` and submit the request to the Servlet.

```
<form action="passtopayment" method="post">
       <!-- HTML controls -->
       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is detailed [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm)

Comment: Also, `doPost` and `doGet` should not have the same behavior.